# Canvas running in a visual studio code extension errors, saying module was compiled by an earlier version that the one running

Tags: javascript, canvas

When running a visual studio code extension using canvas to generate image error logs, I get a problem when in the test enviroment stating that

> node_modules/canvas.node was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 115. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 116. Please try re-compiling or re-installing the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`)..

This is strange because I'm using the latest version of mode, and running canvas outside of the visual studio code extension works.

I used yarn ,updated node to the latest version , rebuilt all the extensions, deleted node modules and then reinstalled, rebuilt using --rebuild-binary